# How to access EMR Web interfaces through SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, ssh-tunnel, ssm

We use EMR web interfaces like Zeppelin and YARN ResourceManager. For EMR hosted in a private subnet, we need to use a bastion host in the public subnet. We also use the same bastion for SSH into the EMR master.

However, now SSM offers a better way to SSH into EMR master without a bastion host.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/replacing-a-bastion-host-with-amazon-ec2-systems-manager/

Is there a way to also use EMR web interfaces in my laptop's browser through SSM without a bastion?

Comment: Never mind. The AWS customer support responded that it's not possible yet, and that they can't confirm whether there plans to add this feature in the future.

Comment: Can you view EMR Web interface via bastion? using SSH tunnel? I am not able to view my web interface via bastion

Comment: I think the process is described in section "Dynamic port forwarding to access Hadoop applications web UIs" on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securing-access-to-emr-clusters-using-aws-systems-manager/